# LINQ Select a List of List with DISTINCT

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

imagine to have a class (and corresponding db table) as follows

```
class Price{
    int ItemID;
    int ItemTypeID;
    string ItemName;
    string ItemTypeName;
    float Price;
}
```

I am seraching for a new to query it via LINQ in order to get the list of distinct Items  (possibly with the use of Take() and Skip() methods) and nested the list of all associated prices.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: To make the question simpler here's an example

Imagine to have 3 "prices" as following

```
1, 1, Ball, Blue, 10 
1, 2, Ball, Red,  20 
2, 1, Frisbee, Blue, 30
```

I would like to put them in a simplified structure

`List<Item>`

where

```
class Item
{
    string ItemName;
    string ItemTypeName;
    List<Price> Prices;
}
```

and

```
class Price
{
    float Price;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you want a GroupBy.  Try something like this.

```
var result = dbContext.Prices
    .GroupBy(p => new {p.ItemName, p.ItemTypeName)
    .Select(g => new Item
                     {
                         ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                         ItemTypeName = g.Key.ItemTypeName,
                         Prices = g.Select(p => new Price 
                                                    {
                                                        Price = p.Price
                                                    }
                                           ).ToList()

                     })
     .Skip(x)
     .Take(y)
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx), like this:

```
var results = _dbContext.Prices
    .Distinct()
    .Skip(15)
    .Take(5);
```

**Edit:**
To populate `List<Item>` with a list of prices for each item as you asked you should use a `GROUPBY` like this:

```
var results = _dbContext.GroupBy( i => new { i.ItemName, i.ItemTypeName })
    .Select( g => new Item()
        {
            ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
            ItemTypeName = g.Key.ItemTypeName,
            Prices = g.Select( p => new Price(){Price = p.Price})
         });
```

After that you can applay `Take` and `Skip` the same way as in the first query.

Comment: This was the [first thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) that came up on Google search when searching for "distinct linq".

Comment: This would give the list of Prices. I'll update the question to make it clearer

Comment: `.Take(5).Skip(15)` will always result in an empty enumeration. I know it's just a sample, but I thought I'd point it out anyway to remove confusion. I'd swap the two calls around for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Mike, I don't know how you got 2 great comments vote, but your comment has been marked as useless because of its out of scope and self righteous tone. Regards